# How to create a sensu check

Tags: sensu

I have created a shell script. I want sensu to run that script on the selected node that are identified using the chef roles. I want to create a sensu check to monitor this particular check using the shell script.

Comment: Please post your code or what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 2):

Sensu can make use of any script which uses these exist statuses:

- **0** = OK
- **1** = Warning
- **2** = Critical

Write your shell script to run whichever tests you want, and exit with the correct value.

Next, configure your check to be called in a checks configuration file:

```
{
  "checks": {
    "<check_name>": {
      "command": "<path_to_script> <arguments>",
      ... other check definitions here...
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, make sure that the check is implemented as a standalone or subscription check.

- Sensu [standalone check](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.0/reference/checks.html#standalone-checks)
- Sensu [subscription check](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/clients.html#client-subscriptions)

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other answer, you can use this as a template. Is a very simple check in bash but it returns the correct outputs for sensu.

```
#!/bin/bash

CHECK="your check goes here"

if [CHECK something]; then
  echo "WARNING!"
  exit 1
else
  echo "OK!"
  exit 0
fi

echo "Unknown Error"
exit 3
```